# In terms of call-return behaviour, how are the fork() and exec() system calls different from other system calls?

Tags: c, unix, fork, exec, manpage

Fork returns twice-

- once in parent
- once in child

**But, how is exec() different from other system calls in terms of call and return behaviour?**

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return at all... unless there's an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are a *few* which don't obey the "returns once" paradigm.

A call to `fork()` returns once *or* twice - the latter on success where it returns once in the parent and once in the child, the former on failure where it simply returns once in the parent.

A call to `exec()` will return on failure but, if successful, the current process is simply overwritten with a new program.

There are others, such as `exit()` or `abort()`, which are not expected to return at all.

Comment: For future reference if anyone is wondering where this information can be found there is an entry in [`man exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) --- `"The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error."`

Comment: And `setjmp()` can return more than once if the `jmp_buf` it saves is `longjmp`'d too.

Comment: Nitpick: `setjmp` / `longjmp` are C standard library functions, not system calls. (They don't require kernel assistance.)

Comment: @paxdiablo, Strictly speaking, `exit(3)` is not a system call, but a library function, as it has to deal with the `atexit(3)` installed callbacks, after which, it should call `_exit(2)`.  The same thing applies to `abort(3)` which normally translates into a call to `kill(2)`.  But are good examples anyway.